# Images to be displayed in sequence order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a slider But I am going some where wrong in my logic. I am able to show all the images, but not in an order. So initially image1 after that image2.. the sequence is going wrong in my logic. 
And the image should load as we enter into the browser, it took some time to load.

here is the live demo link:

http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9c/2#

**HTML**

```
<div id="panel">
  <div id="title">
  </div>
  <img id="imageSlide" alt="" src="" width="250px"/>
  <div id="desc">
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    //Local XML Data
    var slideXML = "<rss version='2.0'><channel>";
    slideXML += "<title>IMAGES</title>";
    slideXML += "<images>";
    slideXML += "<image>";
    slideXML += "<title>Image 1</title>";
    slideXML += "<url>http://www.academy-florists.com/images/shop/thumbnails%5CValentines_Day_flowers.jpg</url>";
    slideXML += "<desc>Description For Image 1</desc>";
    slideXML += "</image>";
    slideXML += "<image>";
    slideXML += "<title>Image 2</title>";
    slideXML += "<url>http://www.everythingbuttheprincess.com/assets/images/babies-in-bloom-fuchsia-flower_thumbnail.jpg</url>";
    slideXML += "<desc>Description For Image 2</desc>";
    slideXML += "</image>";
    slideXML += "<image>";
    slideXML += "<title>Image 3</title>";
    slideXML += "<url>http://www.behok.ru/i/a/cat/gerbera.jpg</url>";
    slideXML += "<desc>Description For Image 3</desc>";
    slideXML += "</image>";
    slideXML += "<image>";
    slideXML += "<title>Image 4</title>";
    slideXML += "<url>http://www.thebutterflygrove.com/images/thumbnails/0/200/200/thumbnail_flower-decor-makpk.jpg</url>";
    slideXML += "<desc>Description For Image 4</desc>";
    slideXML += "</image>";
    slideXML += "<image>";
    slideXML += "<title>Image 5</title>";
    slideXML += "<url>http://www.thebutterflygrove.com/images/thumbnails/0/200/200/thumbnail_flower-decor-makpk.jpg</url>";
    slideXML += "<desc>Description For Image 5</desc>";
    slideXML += "</image>";
    slideXML += "<image>";
    slideXML += "<title>Image 6</title>";
    slideXML += "<url>http://gameinfestedent.com/gallery_photo/medium_image/image1322820610_MainPurpleOrchids3_1a.jpg</url>";
    slideXML += "<desc>Description For Image 6</desc>";
    slideXML += "</image>";
    slideXML += "</images>";
    slideXML += "</channel></rss>";

    //Parse XML content
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(slideXML);
    var $xmldata = $(xmlDoc);

    //Find Total No of Image
    var maximages = ($xmldata.find("images").find("image").length);


    $(function() {
        //FadeIn/FadeOut Image on Set Time Interval on Slide
        setInterval(Slider, 2500);
    });

    var prevIndex = 0;

    function Slider() {
        $('#imageSlide').fadeOut("slow", function() {
            var shuffleIndex = Math.round((Math.random() * (maximages - 1)));
            if (prevIndex == shuffleIndex) {
                if (prevIndex >= (maximages - 1)) {
                    shuffleIndex--;
                } else {
                    shuffleIndex++;
                }
            }
            prevIndex = shuffleIndex;
            $("#panel").fadeIn("slow").css('background', '#000');

            var title = $xmldata.find("images").find("image:eq(" + shuffleIndex + ")").find("title").text();
            $("#title").text(title).fadeIn("slow");

            var imgurl = $xmldata.find("images").find("image:eq(" + shuffleIndex + ")").find("url").text();
            $(this).attr('src', imgurl).fadeIn("slow");

            var desc = $xmldata.find("images").find("image:eq(" + shuffleIndex + ")").find("desc").text();
            $("#desc").text(desc).fadeIn("slow");

        });
    }

});
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Which order do you expect and why you're using random numbers to determine the next index to show? That's paradox...

Comment: _the sequence is going wrong in my logic_ then don't use `Math.random` to get the next image ;) You should also save the result of `$xmldata.find("images").find("image:eq(" + shuffleIndex + ")")` into a variable as you're using it more than once. And better use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

Comment: he does: `prevIndex = shuffleIndex;` ;)

Comment: @keyur at codebins.com : I am facing a problem with image sequence order. Please help me out with demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9c/23 ?

```
      if  ( prevIndex < maximages ){
       shuffleIndex = prevIndex;
       prevIndex++; 
      }
      else {
        prevIndex=0;
        shuffleIndex=prevIndex;
        prevIndex++;
      }
```

Comment: In the first iteration as all the images complete one cycle, then in the second iteration the first image is repeating twice and the process continues like that only

Comment: Hi I need another help from you. There is another issue for me in my approach

Comment: I am creating a thumbnail timer to my slider. I need some help from you.

Comment: here is the link I commented the code which I tried, please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841284/thumbnail-timer-for-the-image-slider and the reference for that thumbnail is https://store.sap.com/sap/cpa/repository/store/sapstore/US/default.html It should be created as it is in this reference site

Answer (score 0):

This could be a sequential order:

```
var i = 0;

    function Slider() {
        $('#imageSlide').fadeOut("slow", function() {

            if(i == maximages) i = 0;
            $("#panel").fadeIn("slow").css('background', '#000');

            var title = $xmldata.find("images").find("image:eq(" + i + ")").find("title").text();
            $("#title").text(title).fadeIn("slow");

            var imgurl = $xmldata.find("images").find("image:eq(" + i + ")").find("url").text();
            $(this).attr('src', imgurl).fadeIn("slow");

            var desc = $xmldata.find("images").find("image:eq(" + i + ")").find("desc").text();
            $("#desc").text(desc).fadeIn("slow");

            i++;

        });
    }
```